# retrieve week number from datetime excel in python

Tags: python, pandas, date, week-number

I open .xslx with pandas.

| value | date of pickup |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 03.08.2022 11:24 |
| ABC234 | 27.07.2022 15:45 |
| ABC434 | 18.05.2022 02:35 |
| ABVC122 | 28.07.2022 10:10 |

I need to keep only rows for previuos week. In my example today is 03.08.2022 wk number 31 I expect to see these rows:

| value | date of pickup |
| --- | --- |
| ABC234 | 27.07.2022 15:45 |
| ABVC122 | 28.07.2022 10:10 |

I tried this:
#remove week_num not in range
df = df.drop([datetime.date(df['date of pickup']).isocalendar()[1] != weekly_num])

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you for your support
Angelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'date':pd.date_range("2022-07-01", "2022-08-03", periods=4)})
df[(df['date'] <= pd.to_datetime("today") - datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)) & (df['date'] >= pd.to_datetime("today") - datetime.timedelta(weeks=2))]
```

output

```
value   date
c       2022-07-23
```

Next time if you can provide the dataframe creation code, it will be easier for us to answer your question.

Comment: Hello Osca, thank you for your reply and sorry for missing code. Here is my code:   ----------------                                     
import pandas as pd
import datetime
my_date = datetime.date.today() # if date is 01/01/2018
year, week_num, day_of_week = my_date.isocalendar()

weekly_num = week_num -1

df = pd.read_csv('C:\_est\test.csv', sep=";", encoding='windows-1252', low_memory=False)
df = df.drop([datetime.date(df['date of pickup']).isocalendar()[1] != weekly_num])

df.to_csv('C:\_est\test2.csv', sep=';', index=False, encoding='windows-1252')

Comment: that's not what I meant by sharing the dataframe creation code. Anyway, my code already demonstrates how to do it. You can use it on your data.